# My project on Actions On Google is showing submission failed while releasing

Tags: actions-on-google

My project on Actions On Google is showing submission failed while realising yet I have done all the things correct and I'm struggling to find a good reason[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxEIi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Typically if a release was denied, they have sent an email giving the reason, or clicking on the details of the release will give details why it was denied.